# Regarding Adobe Flex Remoting Frameworks

Tags: php, remoting

I currently develop **Rich Internet Applications** using **Adobe Flex** for the front-end and **PHP** for the back-end.

I've until now used **AMFPHP v1.9** to handle communication between the two layers. I've also run into some (minor) bugs/defects while using AMFPHP.

I've also heard of other frameworks, those being:

**Sabre AMF**

**WebOrb for PHP**

**AMFPHP v2.0**

and

**Zend AMF**

I'd like to know which of those is the **most robust** and which has the **larget userbase** so I can best choose which to use in future projects. Would be great to have some input from **people who have used one of those frameworks** before.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's quite hard to answer precisely to your question, I do not think that someone is spending money in order to do market research on the largest userbase. I can say that Adobe is investing resources in Zend AMF - there is a partnership between both companies - you may take that into consideration when choosing the framework.

Also WebOrb for PHP is more than just remoting, it also provides messaging (consumer and producers) - if this matter for you it's a big advantage.